# I have calculated dimension for my parameter where equals - All. however, I also want it to return null as 0

Tags: tableau-api

IIF(

```
[Parameters].[Year] = 'All'

, 1=1


, [Parameters].[Year] = STR(YEAR([Date]))
```

)

tableau if parameters return no match than return 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, will return 1 when finds a value, 0 when it doesn't

```
INT([Parameters].[Year] = 'All' OR [Parameters].[Year] = STR(YEAR([Date])))
```

Comment: Thanks Andy - Still having issues with the chart -  if null the chart disappears  - Is this because I have this linked to another calculated field     IIF( [Town] = 'All'     , 1=1      , [Town] = [Town_1]) ?  If yes, then how do I change the town to include null?

Comment: How are you using it? I assumed the filter was to add all to a parameter, but is there more to it? I'm assuming if you have no data in a chart it is disappearing?

Comment: The chart is disappearing because there is no data - when I select a Dept with no data.

Comment: Hi Andy. I'm using a 2nd calculated field to return -- IIF( [Dept] = 'All' , 1=1 , [Dept] = [Dept_1])   -- but I want it to return 0 if null  -- to stop the chart from disappearing.